# Angular redirect to previous page after login not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I've tried using the solution below to redirect user to previous page after sign in but it does not redirect right away to the previous url. It goes to "/" route. When I hit F5 to refresh page, it finally goes to the state.url captured before.

Here is my `auth.guard.ts`

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let url: string = state.url;
    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin')) {
        console.log("logged in");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Could not authenticate');
        this.router.navigate(['/login'],{ queryParams : { 'redirectURL' : url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

How do I make it go right away to state.url after login?

Edit: I added a `console.log(route)` right after the `console.log("logged in")` output and there is no object attached to `queryParams` attribute. 
I was expecting to see the `redirectURL` attached.

[image]

Comment: Why not use [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)? By the way: You can write another navigate in LoginComponent by query url.

Comment: @Numichi I'm using auth.guard.ts because that was the most common solution I've found searching on the internet, so decided to give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue with adding a cookie to store the previous URL.
So `canActive@auth.guard.ts` turned out like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let url: string = state.url;

    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('redirectToPage', '' + url);
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Next step, added this on layout.component.ts

```
let redir = localStorage.getItem('redirectToPage');
if(redir.includes("mypath/")){
    this.router.navigate([redir]);
} else {
    this.router.navigate(['/homepage']);
}
```

Once into the requested page, I removed `redirectToPage` from `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

You can send the URL before going to the login and use it as below

```
@Component({ ... })
class SomePageComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}
  checkLogin() {
    if (!this.auth.loggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login`], { queryParams: { redirectTo: this.route.snapshot.url } });
    }
  }
}
```

So then in your login Component you can access to the queryParams like this

```
@Component({...})
class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  backToPreviousPage() {
    this.router.navigate([this.route.snapshot.queryParam.get('redirectTo')]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `route.snapshot.paramMap.get('previousUrl');`

Try like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRoute, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let url: string = route.snapshot.paramMap.get('previousUrl');
    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin')) {
        console.log("logged in");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Could not authenticate');
        this.router.navigate(['/login'],{ queryParams : { 'redirectURL' : url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Property 'snapshot' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot' " when using the route.snapshot.paramMap.get('previousUrl')

Comment: Check modified answer. `route: ActivatedRoute`

Comment: now it is telling me it is not the correct implementation for canActivate. error says: Property 'snapshot' is missing in type 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot' but required in type 'ActivatedRoute'. the angular version I'm using is 5.